# Javascript : How can i add "&times;" in a button using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a java script code that when i click submit button it will add list in my List items. but i want my list to have and "X" button or specifically "×" for deleting purpose. my code goes like this :

```
    const closeBtn = document.createElement('button');

    closeBtn.className = "closeBtn";

    closeBtn.type = "button";

    closeBtn.textContent = "&times;";
```

But instead of getting the X button i want, i get a button like this:

[image: this]

Comment: `$times;` != `&times;`

Comment: Are you sure you want × and not ❌?

Comment: Sorry my typo is in my question not in my code. hehe i use &times;

Comment: No you don't. That image tells us you use `$`.

Comment: i mean my typo is here in stackoverflow but i use &times; in my actual code sorry

Comment: Then from where does the screenshot come?

Comment: stackflow codes not my main code ofc for privacy purpose

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First use `&times;` and not `$times;`.

Second, use `.innerHTML` and not `textContent`.

```js
const closeBtn = document.createElement('button');
closeBtn.className = "closeBtn";
closeBtn.type = "button";
closeBtn.innerHTML = "&times;" //String.fromCharCode("&times;");

document.querySelector('.content').append(closeBtn)
```

```css
.closeBtn{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
```

CSS Way:

You can find the Unicode for the character and use it with css. This is better as CSS is lighter compared to JS

```css
.closeBtn{
  font-size: 20px;
}
.closeBtn::before {
  content: "\2715";
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <button class='closeBtn'></button>
</div>
```

#### Reference:

- [Unicode characters - HTML Symbols](https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/unicode)

Comment: And third, make the font larger. My eyesight isn't what it used to be...

Comment: Yep. (Though my comment was more for the OP, I didn't mean to criticise your answer.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I got that, but since we did not have definition for `closeBtn` class, though of updating myself. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should, use `.innerHTML` and not `textContent`.

```js
const closeBtn = document.createElement('button')
closeBtn.className = 'closeBtn'
closeBtn.type = 'button'
closeBtn.innerHTML = '&times;'

const content = document.getElementById('content')
content.append(closeBtn)
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```